# Get yesterday midnight date javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I would like to get 2 date variable, one corresponding to midnight yesterday and another corresponding to midnight today. Example: We are on 2021-01-19T10: 42: 00Z.
I need :

```
Yesterday = 2021-01-18T00: 00: 00Z
Today = 2021-01-19T00: 00: 00Z
```

for that I did:

```
let date = new Date()
let yesterday = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1)).setHours(0,0,0,0)
```

But this return :

```
Yesterday = 2021-01-17T23: 00: 00Z
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: This is primarily a timezone issue but it sounds like you aren't aware of that. Are you looking for midnight on the server? Midnight where the user is? Or midnight UTC?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours is likely what you want ... but yes, it's a classic timezone, or daylight saving, issue. Also, never trust user date for anything non-user related.

Comment: I would like midnight on the server to then make requests on my Mongo db to retrieve all the entries present between these 2 dates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `setUTCHours` instead of `setHours`

```js
const today = new Date();
today.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log("Today: ", today);

const yesterday = new Date();
yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
yesterday.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log("Yesterday: ", yesterday);
```

Comment: This does not work for every date (if I start with `new Date("2020-01-01T10:42:00")` I get 1am on Jan 1 and 1am on Jan 18 2021). It also assumes midnight UTC.

Comment: No, it works with `new Date("2020-01-01T10:42:00")` as well. It displays `2019-12-31T00:00: 00Z`

Comment: Thanks this solves my problem! And many thanks for the whole code: D

Comment: Sorry, made a stupid mistake, this works.